# How to add own middleware on third-party package route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

**My systems:**

Passport Version: `10.1.3`

Laravel Version: `6.20.16`

PHP Version: `7.4.14`

Database Driver & Version: `10.5.8`-`MariaDB`

. . .

**Description:**

We use the Laravel Passport package in our project. This package defines several routes for our project. Including the `/oauth/authorize` route. We want one of our middleware to be applied to only this route without making any changes to the Passport package.

How should we do this?
I searched but did not find anything about it.

. . .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Route::middleware('my_middleware')->group(function () {
//a function that includes routes
}

Comment: Indeed overwrite the route declaration.